# Удаление дублей страниц с сайта

Tags: html

На моём сайте обнаружилось 740 дублей. Я не разу не удаляла дубли с сайта, подскажите как это сделать. Я хотела через 301-редирект. Я правильно понимаю, что нужно для каждой страницы прописать этот код в файл htacces?
Например так:

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site.ru/url первой дубль страницы
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/url главной страницы$1 [R=301,L]
```

и снова

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site.ru/url второй дубль страницы
    RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/url главной страницы$1 [R=301,L]
```

и так для каждого url-дубля??? Или я что-то не так понимаю. Может можно как то одним разом удалить все дубли у меня всё таки 740 дублей

Comment: Для начала, не плохо было бы провести анализ и понять, откуда у вас столько дублей, что это за страницы, откуда и так далее. Устранить причины(если возможно) их возникновения и дубли сами уйдут